# Grails unit tests all pass but console returns fatal error

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have a test suite that is passing yet returning a fatal error:

`| Completed 7 unit tests, 0 failed in 0m 2s

| Error Fatal error running tests: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

| Tests FAILED  - view reports in ~/Development/Projects/myProject/target/test-reports`

Using --stacktrace doesn't provide *any* additional information. The full report shows each test case passing, as they should be.

Has anyone encountered this before? This is my first time seeing it and I can't trace what it's from.

EDIT: I should mention it produces this error regardless of which test-suite is run

Comment: After restarting the Grails console this disappeared... really no idea what caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any integration test on your project? The Grails project has a folder that you could create integration tests. Even all unit tests passed, it's possible some problems related with other kind of tests diferent of unit tests. Try clean the project and reports and run the tests. This way cannot resolve the problem, but you will make sure that no garbage is influencing the tests.

I hope I have helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, cleaned the project and the integration tests are passing. It's super odd. Restarting the grails console made the error go away, but it randomly came back a few hours later and then disappeared again and I have yet to see it since.